# Rust vs Golang, overall for smart contract development

Tags: golang, rust

Assuming I do not know anything about these two languages (`rust` & `go`), I know `rust` is being used to write contracts for `solana` and I do not have much idea of `golang`, I am thinking of learning one of these two `solana` is getting popular these days and I have heard much about `golang` what should I start, also I already know `solidity` and use `hardhat` for `ethereum`, should I shift to `solana`, or continue ? Or if there is another good option please guide me through I am very starting of my web3 career. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to concentrate and refine your Solidity knowledge. Conserve your time and energies by keeping them concentrated at your strongest point. You gain more by finding a rich mine and mining it deeper, than by flitting from one shallow mine to another — intensity defeats extensity every time.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that but also I want to explore more at the same time,  since I do not have any work right now, I am already at advanced level in `solidity` and I am finding it difficult to find a job, so why not try something else.